Can a positive charged body moving inside a positively charged hollow sphere crash into the sides?
One can use the Gauss' law, or the solid angle approach to prove that the electric potential inside a homogeneously charged hollow sphere is uniform. This implies that a positively body moving inside a positively charged sphere experiences no electric force.
Does that mean that it can just crash into one of the sides? If we ignore non-electrostatic forces, can it simply escape the sphere? What kind of approximations / assumptions are we using here? When do they break down?

just because inside there is no force it does not mean that when "crashing" through, what ever that may mean, there is no force on it once it gets outside the sphere, in fact there is a force, and repulsive one between positive charges.

@hyportnex But what does crashing mean? The body can approach the surface to an arbitrarily small distance, and the argument would still work that there is no net force on it.

"Crashing"? Must be a miracle, and since you used that term, you should know what you meant by it.

I answered your question without the unclear "crash" part.

According to Gauss' law, a positively charged body inside such a positively charged hollow sphere does produce an outward directed electric field inside the sphere! Thus, also the electrical potential cannot be constant there, in contrast to when there is no charged body inside, or when an electric test charge is vanishingly small. However, due to Coulombs law for the spherical charge distribution, there is no force exerted on the charged body.
PS: If you add a second charged body into the hollow sphere, or split the first one, the two charged bodies will repel each other and will be accelerated towards the sphere wall. If the acceleration is strong enough, they could penetrate and even pass the shell. Outside they would experience an additional outward acceleration due to electrostatic repulsion by the shell.

Yes, but there is no electric force acting on the charged body, as it cannot act on itself. The electric field experienced by the body is also uniform.

@GingerBadger There is, indeed,  no force of the spherical symmetric charge shell on the charged body inside the sphere, because you can divide the body charge into infinitesimal components which do not experience a force. This is a known fact following from Coulombs law for spherical symmetric charge distributions.
